# Using forEach in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, exchangewebservices

I am trying to use `forEach()` method in Java 8.

My code looks like the following:

```
String c = service.resolveName("Example").forEach((NameResolution c->{Implementation}));
```

Here, `forEach` method is not executed for a `List<String>`. It's executed for a `List<NameResolution>`. Now, when I am trying to iterate `obj` of `NameResolution`, it still shows the `String` operation.

Can we use `forEach()` for `List`s of non-`String` values? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you should fix your lambda expression to :

```
service.resolveName("Example").forEach((NameResolution c)->{...});
```

This is assuming `service.resolveName("Example")` returns a `List<NameResolution>` (or some other `Collection<NameResolution>`).

Note the `forEach` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Or just write `.forEach( c -> { … } )`